# MvvmCross support for Windows 10 apps(UWP)

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I have created Windows 8.1 app with mvvmcross. Now I have migrated the same app into windows 10 (UWP) app. I am not getting any mvvmcross reference issue.
While running the application I am getting splash screen, after some minutes I am getting below error :

> An exception of type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException'
>   occurred in Cirrious.CrossCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find plugin type in assembly.

I have done step by step debug solution the Setup. `Initialize()` method is not calling while app launch.

Can you please let me know? Is mvvmcross library compatible with windows 10 apps(UWP)?

Comment: Do you have a small sample repo where i could reproduce this?

Comment: I've now add my own UWP project to my app, and i got the same kind of error. It seems when adding MvvmCross to a UWP project some references are missing. I added those mannually and evething worked fine.

Comment: Another update: the nuget specs have been updated to support this now. A new project type for UWP will be added soon too. I'll let you know when it is ready.

Comment: Hello @Martijn00, do you know if the UWP project type has been added? Thx!

Comment: @JSalazar Yes, this has been added some time ago.